# (discord.py) Is there any way for the on_message event to look into an embedded rather than a normal message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord.py bot that looks for given keywords in every message with the on_message event. While this works great with normal text, I can't get it to work with an embedded message which is what I need. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`message.embeds` will get you a list of `Embed` objects. You might try something like

```
def check_all_message(check_for, message):
    if check_for in message.content:
        return True
    for e in message.embeds:
        if any(item and check_for in item for item in (e.title, e.footer, e.description)):
            return True
        if e.fields:
            for field in e.fields:
                if check_for in field.name or check_for in field.value:
                    return True
    return False

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    if check_all_message("apple", message):
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, 'You said "apple"!')
```